# Double Fusing - PTC and Normal

Tags: fuses

I'm working on a power distribution board for a couple of low voltage PCBs (mainly seperate microcontrollers on individual PCBs).
The idea of the power distribution board is to regulate the input voltage to it (12V) down to 5V and connect it to the microcontroller PCBs. Each microcontroller PCB will be connected to it's own header on the power distribution board and will have it's own regulator and fuse on the power distribution board.

My idea was to put the glass visible standard fuses on the power distribution board for each header so that at a glance I can see which ones were blown or not. Then I also thought for an added layer of protection, I should add PTC fuses on the input at the microcontroller boards.

The microcontroller boards may be unreachable in some cases, hence why I'm choosing PTC for them.

**Is it worth double fusing? Am I not taking into account some side-affect of this?**

Comment: Normally the PTC dominates and would not allow enough current to pop a fuse. One fuse per distribution to multiple PTC's would make sense.

Comment: Using a linear regulator to drop 12 to 5V is very inefficient.  There are much better ways to do this.

Comment: You can have active current limiting with voltage regulation and thermal protection on each board with a DC ok indicator .

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I probably should have said buck converter, sorry. That sounds very nice but I want to keep all the power stuff (glass fusing, buck down, reuglation) all on the power distribution board so that the others who are designing the microcontroller boards just need to put a PTC on their end and can assume they're getting a nice 5V.

Comment: @Sparky256 You're saying have one glass fuse at the main power in to the power distribution board and then PTC fuses at each of the microcontroller board inputs? In that case, can I just put a main glass fuse at the input of the power distribution board and then also put the PTC fuses right before the header on the power distribution board that go to the microcontroller boards just to keep it all in one place? I've also heard that PTCs take longer to "pop".

Comment: That's fine for steady current but not step reactive loads, then you get load regulated supply noise, unless you have a heavy bus and stipulate the load reactance or surge current levels.  Then troubleshooting becomes an issue from conducted crosstalk. Unless you stipulate the decoupling BW requirements

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I'm not sure what all that means :D (not great at power electronics) The microcontrollers are just gonna be running some accelerometers, temp sensors.

Comment: You can also put polyfuses on the PDU and give them indicators if you know the card limits.

Comment: @AlfroJang80. PTC's do not 'pop'. They are resettable fuses in that when they cool down they allow current to flow again, assuming the problem was fixed. They need less then a second to respond to over current which causes them to get hot, but that makes their resistance go way up to cut back the current.

Comment: @Sparky256 Yes, sorry that is what I meant. I didn't know what the correct word to use was so I called it "pop". I think it's called tripped. I think I'll go with the glass fuse on power distribution board at the main input to it as well as a glass fuse right before the header leaves the power distribution board. And as a last layer, I'll put a PTC at the input of the microcontroller boards. My only concern with the PTC is that I wouldn't actually know where the issue is if it keeps resetting,

Comment: I see you don't have much experience. So I'll stop repeating myself, besides fuses can add more reliability problems if selected wrong